# How can I get an Image from a website through RSS feeds?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, rss, nsxmlparser

I am currently building an iOS RSS feed app and it will have a tableView displaying the feeds. I wish to put an ImageView in each table view cell and the image will be from the website of that RSS feed. I am currently using the NSXMLParserDelegate in my file. I just need to know how to get the image from the website... Here is just an example of the rss feed i am using. http://www.forbes.com/most-popular/feed/ Is it possible to get an image from this URL? Thanks for any help! This is my code so far.What do i need to add in order to get the image?

```
#import "JSSSecondViewController.h"
#import "JSSDetailViewController.h"
#import "JSSFirstViewController.h"

@interface JSSSecondViewController () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;
}

@end

@implementation JSSSecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView2 reloadData];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView2 indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}



@end
```

This is the XML I will be parsing...

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>CNET Gaming</title>
<link>http://www.cnet.com/#ftag=CADa872701</link>
<description>
Game on! Get the latest in gaming news, video game reviews, computer games & video game consoles.
</description>
<language>en</language>
<pubDate>Thu, 10 Apr 2014 23:23:50 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 10 Apr 2014 23:23:50 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>2</ttl>
<image>
<title>CNET Gaming</title>
<url>
http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/ne/gr/prtnr/CNET_Logo_150.gif
</url>
<link>http://www.cnet.com/#ftag=CADa872701</link>
</image>
<item>
<title>
Get a Moga Mobile Gaming System for Android for $13 shipped
</title>
<link>
http://www.cnet.com/news/get-a-moga-mobile-gaming-system-for-android-for-13-shipped/#ftag=CADa872701
</link>
<description>
This Bluetooth game controller sold for $49.99 when it debuted last year.<img width='1' height='1' src='http://cnet.com.feedsportal.com/c/34938/f/645455/s/38e7da50/sc/5/mf.gif' border='0'/><br clear='all'/><br/><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/1/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/2/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/rc/3/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/a2.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/a2.img" border="0"/></a><img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/193360522992/u/191/f/645455/c/34938/s/38e7da50/sc/5/a2t.img" border="0"/>
</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 10 Apr 2014 23:21:10 GMT</pubDate>
<guid>
http://www.cnet.com/news/get-a-moga-mobile-gaming-system-for-android-for-13-shipped/#ftag=CADa872701
</guid>
<dc:creator>Rick Broida</dc:creator>
<media:thumbnail url="http://cnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2014/04/02/0eeab98d-efb9-4779-a973-7b709f4fbb06/thumbnail/300x230/c7edbbac37a02b874a7bcfe373f6f9ec/moga-mobile.jpg"/>
</item>
<item>
<title>Xbox boss: Microsoft won't sell us off</title>
<link>
http://www.cnet.com/news/xbox-boss-microsoft-wont-sell-us-off/#ftag=CADa872701
</link>
```

This is just a snippet. It contains a reference to an image. In this case, how can i display the image in my tableView?

Comment: Does the XML for the RSS feed include an image URL? Your question doesn't provide any details to provide real help and your question shows little effort on your part to look into a solution. What do you have? What have you tried? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: It would help to include in your question some relevant XML that you are trying to parse. Don't make others have to do much research. The question should be self contained.

Comment: Again, just post a relevant snippet from the XML, no need for a giant file. But I don't see any references to images in there.

Comment: check my edit @rmaddy it now contains a new rss that has images...

Comment: You need to parse the `url` tag and get the URL. Then request the data for that URL and create a `UIImage` from that `NSData`.

Comment: I'm sorry i am new to iOS. Can you explain to me how to parse the url tag or it's also ok to give me a link to a tutorial @rmaddy

Comment: You already have code for parsing the title and links tags. Getting the url tag is similar.

Comment: So I do the same thing but for the URL of the image? @rmaddy